# how can I configure php swiftmailer to send email

Tags: php, mysql

I have downloaded swiftmailer file library to integrate in my application and after defining my sendmail variable I am having the following error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Connection could not be established with host localhost [No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. #10061]' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ordering\admin\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php:266 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ordering\admin\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php(64): Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->_establishSocketConnection() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\ordering\admin\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(115): Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->initialize(Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\ordering\admin\lib\classes\Swift\Mailer.php(80): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start() #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\ordering\admin\send_mail.php(43): Swift_Mailer->send(Object(Swift_Message)) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\ordering\admin\update_status_divident.php(48): sendMail('nabem.jude@gmai...', 'Gandepuun', 'igbehg@gmail.co...', 'SUCCESSGANDE', 12345, 'localhost') #5 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ordering\admin\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php on line 266
```

Here are my variables

```
<?
$MyEmail=ShowEmail($member_id);
$rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($MyEmail);
$email=$rs['Email'];
$username=$rs['memberID'];

$Mamail='nabem.jude@gmail.com';
$Mapwd='Gandepuun';


$applicationid=12345;
$instanceadd='localhost';
sendMail($Mamail,$Mapwd,$email,$username,$applicationid,$instanceadd);
```

Somebody please help me what should be a variable for `$instanceadd`
Waiting for your prompt answers, please.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used swiftmailer but it looks like it is trying to speak to the SMTP service on your local machine but your local machine is refusing it either because the service is firewalled or you do not have an SMTP service installed.